# Finding a smooth path with exponential decay

Tags: real-analysis

A smooth path is a smooth function $\varphi$ from $[0,1]$ to some topological space. So let's consider $\mathbb R$ with the standard topology. I need to find a path from some fixed $x\in\mathbb R$ to $0$ such that the decay is exponential, i.e. something like $$\varphi(t) = \exp(-\lambda t)x.$$
But clearly $\varphi(1)\neq 0$ so this is not a path. How can I modify my path that I get the desired result? This seems to be an easy question but I struggle for hours now...

Comment: Exponential decay only asymptotically approaches the limiting value, meaning "to $0$ such that the decay is exponential" **means** $\varphi(1) \neq 0$, in fact, it means $\varphi$ is never $0$, only in the limit as the input goes to $\infty$ does $\varphi$ go to zero.  So which do you want?:  $\varphi(1) = 0$ or $\varphi$ exponentially decays to $0$?

Answer (score 0):

How about this: $\varphi (t)=x\exp(1+1/(t-1))$ for $t\in [0,1),$ $\varphi (1) =0.$ We then have $\varphi (0) =x,$ and as $t\to 1^-,$ $\varphi (t) \to 0$ at an "exponential rate".